# Visual Studio 2013 .aspx intellisense not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

In my .aspx page I am trying to write some code but it seems my intellisense is not working. (Visual Studio 2013)

[image]

I tried deleting my v12.suo file but that did not resolve anything. I also tried web essentials and looking around my options but I couldn't get it to work.

So I tried:

- Deleting v12.suo file
- Cleaning/Rebuilding solution
- Web Essentials
- Different options in Tools -> options

Anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: did the intellisense worked before?

Comment: @styx No, not in the aspx pages

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense -> "Show completion list after a character is typed" is checked.

Comment: That's checked, I made sure to uncheck it and recheck it to be sure but it's not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, check that intellisense is enabled, if it is enabled and not appearing you can refresh it, the standard command in visual studio is CTRL+SHIFT+R

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and saw that the first line of my .aspx page containing the "page" directive was underlined. Putting the mouse on it show me that my project was using 2 old references, the bin files were no more available.

I **removed those 2 old references "Web Site > Starting options... > References"** and now the completion/errorcheck of C# directives in this pages is working like a charm.

Hope it can helps..